# INI файлы в C++

Tags: c++

Как лучше и проще реализовать работу с ini файлами ? Именно интересует реализация структуры:

```
;comment
[section]
name=value
```

Можно ведь написать парсер использую функция для работы с файлами ? 
P.S. Не предлагайте готовые решения, кроме встроенных функций, т.к. хочется самому.

Comment: ini - неудобный устаревший формат, лучше сразу берите xml или json

Comment: У меня есть программа, которая хранит изменяемые параметры, как захочет пользователь. Что мне теперь использовать xml или json ? и это тут вообще ни причем.

Comment: "*ini - неудобный устаревший формат*" - кто вам сказал такую чушь? В свой каталог `/etc` загляните для начала.

Comment: `C:\Users\user>cd /etc`
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.

Comment: Тем более - "отучаемся говорить за всех". Впрочем, под Windows - наверняка у вас имеется какой-нибудь php.ini или инишник mysql, посмотрите туда. И то, что у вас нет /etc никак не делает формат ini устаревшим или неудобным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот ещё, pure C: [iniparser](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/). Умеет понимать довольно сложные случаи ([документация](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/html/index.html)).

```
dictionary * ini = iniparser_load( "config.ini" );
char * one = dictionary_get( ini, "first_section:one", "default" );
char * two = dictionary_get( ini, "second_section:two", NULL );
iniparser_freedict(ini);
```

Максимальная длина строки фиксирована, но её можно переопределить при сборке:

```
#define ASCIILINESZ (1024)
```

P.S. Что-то мне его допилить уже захотелось...

Comment: Отдельный плюс поставил бы за последнюю фразу :)

Comment: "`[Section]` `Keyword = value ; comment` is converted to the following key pair: `("section:keyword", "value")`" - разве это правильно? В таком варианте значения заведомо не могут содержать точку с запятой, что выглядит как-то бредово.

Comment: Никто не мешает заключать значения в кавычки. Там других мелочей есть немного, в самой реализации.

Answer (score 7):

Точно не знаю, насколько глубоко вам хочется самому, и насколько низко (в смысле насколько низкоуровневых операций) вы готовы опуститься.

Если вы пишете для Windows и можете использовать WinAPI, тогда 
вы можете воспользоваться функциями `GetPrivateProfileString` и `GetPrivateProfileInt`.

Подробнее:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353.aspx (англ.)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724345.aspx (англ.)

Если вы пишете кроссплатформенно и готовы использовать Boost,
то просто возьмите Program_options.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/program_options.html (англ.)

Если вы хотите полностью реализовать парсер самостоятельно,
посмотрите для вдохоновения проект *inih*. Лучше чем там написано,
всё равно никто не напишет.

- https://github.com/benhoyt/inih (англ.)

Ну и в завершение, для того чтобы ещё более расширить плюрализм мнений
и многообразие выбора, схожий вопрос на SO, в котором вы найдёте множество других не менее интересных альтернатив:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-c (англ.)

Comment: "*Лучше чем там написано, всё равно никто не напишет*": как минимум - в глаза бросаются жёсткие ограничения на размеры строк... Учитывая  `INI_ALLOW_MULTILINE` - неаккуратненько :)

Comment: `GetPrivateProfileString` и `GetPrivateProfileInt` - отвратный вариант. Они будут при каждом вызове заново парсить ini-файл. А при нормальной реализации весь файл надо прочитать и распарсить 1 раз.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что действительно хорошая функция чтения конфигурации должна быть тесно связана с разбором аргументов командной строки и текущими переменными окружения (environment). Т.е. нужна возможность модификации конфигурационного файла переменными окружения  и аргументами, с которыми вызывается программа.

Также привлекательна возможность после прочтения конфигурации сразу получать уже инициализированные из нее (с учетом модификации  аргументами командной строки и environment)  переменные программы.

Если интересно, попробуйте спроектировать такую штуку.

Comment: Ещё весело - запись инишника. С сохранением пользовательского форматирования, хотя бы комментариев. С учётом возможных изменений в самой программе: удаления, добавления, модификации значений/секций/комментов. Больше 15 лет назад бился над такой задачей и даже сделал. Только как - уже не помню :)

Comment: @klopp, насчет записи -- это  точно. Я уж не стал грузить ТС по полной. Кстати, в записи самое сложное (точно сам не знаю как сделать, по крайней мере *сделать просто*) это "мерджинг" изменений конфигов при одновременной работе нескольких экземпляров программы.

Comment: И ещё одна забавная фишка: самоконфиг. Например: `ValidTrueValues = "Yes, True, Yep, Ok" ; влияет на метод get_bool()`, `MultilineCommentPairs = "/*,*/,{{,}}"` и т.д. Но это уже из разряда фантиков :)

Answer (score -1):

> Именно интересует реализация структуры

```
map < string, map <string, string> > ini;
```

Первый ключ - имя секции, второй - имя ключа, значение - значение параметра. Это для случая, когда важно осмысленное содержимое, а не всё, что вообще есть в файле. При желании сюда упихать комментарии, можно использовать пустую строку или `;` в качестве ключа (а при особом желании, строки, начинающиеся с точки с запятой). Но порядок записей всё равно будет меняться при перезаписи.

Если есть желание сохранить и порядок, можно просто сохранить нумерацию в отдельном векторе.